# No app icon on iPhone but does appear on simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, icons

I am trying to find a way where an icon set up on assets folder appears on my device. I have deleted my app and reinstalled it by running project couple of time but with no success.
I am not sure where I am going wrong as I have correct images with correct sizes as there are no warnings on my Xcode. If someone can tell me a way to fix this will be helpful. Thank you. 
Sorry if this has been asked before but the solutions provided didn't really worked for me.

Comment: which version of xcode are you using?

Comment: Version 7.3 (7D175)

Answer (score 0):

command + shift + k , 
Then Run!!

Comment: Nopes. Do we need something in .plist file?